# Newton-Raphson method to solve for dof when performing MLE of a multivariate Student-t distribution using EM

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, expectation-maximization, t-distribution

I am reading the derivation of EM algorithm to estimate the maximum likelihood of a multivariate Student-t distribution $\mathcal{T}(\mathbf{x} \vert \pmb{\mu}, \pmb{\Sigma}, \nu)$ in Kevin Murphy's textbook (*Machine Learning: a probabilistic perspective, section 11.4.5*). I can follow the whole section, but have a concern at the very last step when determining the dof $\nu$.

The E-step for $\nu$ is:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[L_{G}(\nu) \right] = -N \log \Gamma \left(\frac{\nu}{2} \right) + \frac{N\nu}{2} \log \left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right) + \frac{\nu}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left( \bar{\ell}^{(t)}_{i} - \bar{z}_{i}^{(t)} \right),
\tag{11.77}
\label{11.77}
\end{equation}
where $\Gamma(x)$ is the gamma function.

The M-step is to maximize $\mathbb{E}\left[L_{G}(\nu) \right]$ w.r.t. $\nu$ by solving for the root of the first derivative:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \mathbb{E}\left[L_{G}(\nu) \right]}{\partial \nu} = -\frac{N}{2} \Psi \left(\frac{\nu}{2} \right) + \frac{N}{2} \log \left(\frac{\nu}{2} \right) + \frac{N}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \left( \bar{\ell}^{(t)}_{i} - \bar{z}_{i}^{(t)} \right),
\tag{11.78}
\label{11.78}
\end{equation}
where $\Psi(x)$ is the digamma function.

As discussed in the textbook, the root of \eqref{11.78} can be found by using some numerical methods for root finding, such as half-interval method. However, I wonder if we can apply Newton-Raphson method for \eqref{11.78} by taking second derivative:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 \mathbb{E}\left[L_{G}(\nu) \right]}{\partial\nu^{2}} = -\frac{N}{4} \Psi^{(2)} \left(\frac{\nu}{2} \right) + \frac{N}{2\nu},
\end{equation}
where $\Psi^{(2)}(x)$ is the trigamma function.

Given the second derivative, we can apply the Newton-Raphson method to iteratively find the dof $\nu$ as:
\begin{equation}
\nu \gets \nu - \left(\frac{\partial \mathbb{E}\left[L_{G}(\nu) \right]}{\partial \nu}\right)/\left(\frac{\partial^2 \mathbb{E}\left[L_{G}(\nu) \right]}{\partial\nu^{2}}\right).
\end{equation}

My question is if we can apply Newton-Raphson method to find $\nu$. What are the disadvantages of the Newton-Raphson method preventing us from using in this case? I am aware that Newton-Raphson method requires the second derivative, but in this case, the second derivative can be efficiently calculated. Or, I might be wrong because of the complexity of the digamma calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, the Newton-Raphson method could be used here as well. In fact, you can treat it as a root-finding method applied to the (11.78).

The trigamma function does not introduce challenge either. Surely it's not available in a closed form, but so does digamma, and there're efficient numerical procedures to compute both of them, in fact scipy has a generic [scipy.special.polygamma](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.polygamma.html) function that covers both of them.